# Java Applet vs Application

Tags: java, applet

I'm using Java for some time now, so I'm quite familiar with it, BUT for my Barchelor thesis I may be doing Java Applet, and that is something i have never worked with. I know that Applet runs from browser and that it has no access to user filesystem, etc... What i need to know is are there any differences when writing code ?

Project leader told me, that we would like to have someone with experience with Applets. It is that big difference between them ? Can i handle this (master Applets) in one week ?

Project name is "Path Planning Algorithms Visualisation" and that's all i know about it for now.

Comment: applets are beeing thrown away and the support slowly ends (chrome doesn´t support applets anymore), so using applets isn´t a good idea

Comment: [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/)

Comment: Making applets is pretty much like making JFrame applications, only the programs don't have access to files and the applet is embedded in a web page. All you need besides general programming skills is the knowledge of a couple class to extend, a couple of types to create data members of and a couple of methods to override.

Comment: Kevin & @progy_rock have offered some sound advice. Avoid applets like the plague. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java Applet, then you won't have to deal with things like JSP, HTML, CSS, JAVA Script. Everything is done in Java. You can use NetBeans to make your life easier to focus on functionality and no the details of the UI.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you'll need to "master" anything.  You might have to override some methods like init() or paint().  All the code will be java of course, and you'll have to do some html configuration to load the applet and reference classes.

Comment: *"I don't think you'll need to "master" anything."* How many applets have you tried to deploy to the web in the last 6 months? It used to be a PITA, but now more browsers have entirely removed support for them, than still do!

Comment: I agree that applets are ancient history, but op still has to do one for his thesis.  I was just referring to the actual development of the applet if he can get one running in a browser/version that supports it.

Comment: It was *never* simple. The fact is, he should communicate that to whoever specified an applet & let them decide. An application launched by JWS would be simpler, or perhaps replace the applet with JS and the HTML 5 canvas.